# Relation Table between Two database NoSQL and SQL

Tags: c#, sql, service, nosql

I want to create a `Reviews` table in a NoSQL database. Reviews is for Users in SQL database.

My question is how can I get user's full name in reviews with out query in UsersService?
in fact in my sample i query full name from SQLServer Database so it need so performance I don't want this

Please provide suggestions for solving this problem.

Example review

```
sender Akbar Asghari 

review text is here
```

My schema is as shown in this illustration:

[image]

Sorry for my English

Comment: This is a pretty huge task you are undertaking. There is no simple answer. Migrating from a SQL database to a NoSQL database is something people have created entire online classes.

Comment: hi tanks for great answer but how can I handler this can you give me Topic or suggest website for this problem I don't know how to google it :)